# EIX000: (-111) ISAM error: no record found when attempting to get Tables list in Visual Studio with Informix database

Tags: visual-studio-2013, informix

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 and have connected and tested successfully against an Informix 12.05 database. The ODBC driver we're using is the Informix ODBC 4.10.FC3DE. After connecting to the database if I attempt to view the contents of Tables, View, or Procedures I get the above error. If I right-click on Table and choose New Query I get the error, but the can type in and perform a query with no issues.

As per this page, I have verified that the sysutils database does exist:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21504406

Other than the above, I am not finding much that appears to be aimed at this problem.

Any thoughts on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

2019 person here... The answer to this for me was while they setup an ODBC connection to the database, they were pointing to the wrong table.. this error was the one that came up in Visual studio though and it wasn't until I tested with the SDK for informix that lets you get a preview of the table did I figure it out.

Can you connect to the database? yes

can you hit the tables? no

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the coledbp.sql script that came with the SDK as user informix and set up the connection and save the default server in the SetNet32 utility?